# How can I find out which slow script is giving IE problems?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

IE8 is giving me the slow-running script message on load of a page:

> Stop running this script? A script on this page is causing your web
>   browser to run slowly. If it continues to run, your computer might
>   become unresponsive.

However, the webapp I'm debugging is fairly old and has a whole lot of scripts. Is there an easy way for me to find out which of those scripts is causing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure because I don't use IE... But can you do some breakpoint in the console and then reload the page to see if you breakpoint is before or after the slow script?

Comment: This should be as comment

Answer (score 0):

Try the [javascript profiler](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/09/11/introducing-the-ie8-developer-tools-jscript-profiler.aspx) from the debugger.